# Generate maven archetype specifying custom archetype descriptor

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype, archetypes

I would create a Maven archetype starting from my project, so I used this command:

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project
```

After that, I see the generated archetype-metadata.xml in `target/generated-sources/archetype/src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/` folder.

It is there a way to specify to `mvn` to add the command "`filtered=true`" to each "`fileSet`" (i.e. `-Darchetype.filtered=always`)?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I solved thanks to the Velocity template using the parameter: `archetype.filteredExtentions`